# Keyboard types diacritics (¨) instead of double quotes

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

I have a problem with double quotes on my keyboard while working on Linux.

- The double quote my keyboard types is: `¨¨`
- and what I really expect is: `""`

You see the difference there? The first one which my keyboard types is not accepted when I work with R, so I have to copy-paste the correct double quotes from the internet  every time.

This happens only when I work with Linux, and not Windows. Does anyone know how to change it or get it right?

Comment: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=238956 - basically, change your keyboard layout to "QWERTY US" or "QWERTY XX".

Comment: Ps. in the keyboard section of Settings (in Gnome) when you add a layout you can also click on the 3 dots and select "View keyboard layout" to see all the character combinations

Answer (score 7):

A likely cause is that you have your keyboard layout set to *English (US International)*, like I have. This setting enables you to enter international diacritics, but comes with some gotchas.

If you want `"` instead of `¨` use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> (the one next to the Enter key).

If you want `'` instead of `´` use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> (the one next to the Enter key).

Comment: Or it is set to English (UK International) which does not have any plain double-quotes. Just various slanted ones at alt-gr + `V`, `B` and `;` . Only Karlsebal tip works

Answer (score 2):

For me I just type `space` after the diacritic. So `¨`+`space` will yield the expected result for double quotes where hitting `¨` 2 times in a row will print those tiny backticks.

Solution proposed by @Moises with `alt` key does not work for me.

Comment: That's work. Interesting. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late for a new answer now, but i just had the same problem myself.

What did the trick for me was to change the keyboard layout from "English (US intl., with dead keys)" to "English (intl., with AltGr dead keys")

Answer (score 0):

As @Prisoner said, look at: [Single and Double Quotes Not Working - FedoraForum.org](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=238956)

Basically, change your keyboard layout to "QWERTY US" or "QWERTY XX". Hopefully that will work, if not, drop a comment and we'll keep looking.